# Increment Numbers with Alphabets In SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, increment

My Table structure is

```
id    type   no     amount
1     type1  a1      1000
2     type1  a2      2000
3     type2  b1      3000
4     type3  c1      4000
5     type1  a3      5000
6     type2  b2      6000
7     type2  b3      7000
8     type3  c2      8000
```

now i wants to increment the `no` field data based on the `type`.

for example for `type1` the next no is `a4`

and

for numeric only I am using the following code

```
SELECT ISNULL(Max(No),0)+1 AS No FROM table
```

but how to do it for with Alphabets in SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that prefixes are of single character length, you may try following:

```
;with cte as (
    select type, typePrefix = left(no, 1), typeNum = right(no, len(no) - 1)
    from TableName
)
select typePrefix + cast(isnull(max(typeNum), 0) + 1 as varchar(10))
from cte
where type = 'type1'
group by typePrefix
```

But it will not work if you try to generate next `no` for a type which is not in table (e.g. 'type4'). To allow it, you may need a separate table, where prefix for each type is specified:

```
create table TypePrefixes (type varchar(50), prefix varchar(10))
insert into TypePrefixes values ('type1', 'a')
insert into TypePrefixes values ('type2', 'b')
insert into TypePrefixes values ('type3', 'c')
insert into TypePrefixes values ('another_type', 'd')
--etc.
```

In this case, statement to get next `no` will look as:

```
select tp.prefix + cast(isnull(max(cast(right(t.no, len(t.no) - len(tp.prefix)) as int)), 0) + 1 as varchar(20))
from TableName t
    right join TypePrefixes tp on tp.type = t.type
where tp.type = 'type4'
group by tp.prefix
```

Also, you may just wish to calculate `no` for each record on the fly, like:

```
;with cte as (
    select *,
        typeNum = row_number() over (partition by type order by id),
        typePrefix = char(dense_rank() over (order by type) + ascii('a') - 1)
    from TableName
)
select *, No2 = typePrefix + cast(typeNum as varchar(10))
from cte
```

However, the latter is limited in number of distinct types in your table, which should not exceed 26 (so that we not go beyond 'z').

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
SELECT ISNULL(Max(No),0)+1 AS No FROM table group by type
```

Comment: i saw but i thought it would still order by current collation rules

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an UNIQUE index on `No` column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_MyTable_On
ON MySchema.MyTable(On);
GO
```

This unique index will prevent duplicate values but, also, will help the query below.

Second, you could use this script to generate the next `No` for a given letter:

```
DECLARE @Chr CHAR(1);
SET @Chr='A';

BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @LastId INT;
DECLARE @NewNo VARCHAR(...); -- Fill with No's max. length

-- Previous index will help this query
SELECT @LastId=MAX( CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@LastNo,2,8000)) )
FROM MySchema.MyTable x WITH(UPDLOCK) -- It locks the rows to prevent a concurent session to generate the same value (No)
WHERE x.No LIKE @Chr+'%';

SET @NewNo=@Chr+CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ISNULL(@LastId,0)+1);

-- Do whatever you want with the new value: ex. INSERT
INSERT INTO ... (No,...)
VALUES (@NewNo,...);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(2000);
SET @ErrMsg=ERROR_MESSAGE();
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END
RAISERROR(@ErrMsg,16,1);
END CATCH
```

Note #1: This solution should be safe if this is the only way to generate the new values (`@NewNo`).

Note #2: If that SELECT query acquires at least 5000 locks then SQL Server will escalate locks at table/partition level.